# Display the date, like "May 5th", using pythons strftime?

Tags: python, strftime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Date Ordinal Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739241/python-date-ordinal-output)

In Python time.strftime can produce output like "Thursday May 05" easily enough, but I would like to generate a string like "Thursday May 5th" (notice the additional "th" on the date).  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you show us the way you are doing it so we can show you a specific solution.

Comment: His question is quite specific.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: Without code, it's still not really specific enough.  Without code it's "do my homework for me".  With code, however, we can discuss the error.

Comment: S.Lott : I think it's it is. It's straightforward enough to be answerable without a code sample. It's a direct question about a single function (which he's named).

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`strftime` doesn't allow you to format a date with a suffix.

Here's a way to get the correct suffix:

```
if 4 <= day <= 20 or 24 <= day <= 30:
    suffix = "th"
else:
    suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][day % 10 - 1]
```

[**found here**](http://snipplr.com/view/3468/python-date-suffixes-for-strftime/)

### Update:

Combining a more compact solution based on Jochen's comment with [gsteff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891555/display-the-date-like-may-5th-using-pythons-strftime/5891658#5891658):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def suffix(d):
    return {1:'st',2:'nd',3:'rd'}.get(d%20, 'th')

def custom_strftime(format, t):
    return t.strftime(format).replace('{S}', str(t.day) + suffix(t.day))

print custom_strftime('%B {S}, %Y', dt.now())
```

Gives:

`May 5th, 2011`

Comment: `suffix = { 1 : "st", 2 : "nd", 3 : "rd" }.get(day % 10, "th")`

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel - That looks even more clever, but what happens once May Elevenst (May 11st) rolls around?

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel Your expression produces 'st' for '11', 'nd' for '12', 'rd' for '13'. No ?

Comment: The `suffix` implementation above produces the wrong values for 11, 12 and 13.

Comment: time.strftime will take a tuple of 9 elements as its second arg, so t.day wont technically work.  I think t[2] from gsteff is still the best. t[2] will work with time_structs returned by time.localtime or the 9 tuples.

Comment: @Buttons840: I'm using `datetime` rather than `time`

Comment: Thanks. Its quite neat, used it for my JavaScrip code with some modifications.

Comment: I know I'm late but if the day is modulo 20 then there is no need to check if it is in the teens. I suggested an edit with this correction.

Answer (score 19):

This seems to add the appropriate suffix, and remove the ugly leading zeroes in the day number:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

day_endings = {
    1: 'st',
    2: 'nd',
    3: 'rd',
    21: 'st',
    22: 'nd',
    23: 'rd',
    31: 'st'
}

def custom_strftime(format, t):
    return time.strftime(format, t).replace('{TH}', str(t[2]) + day_endings.get(t[2], 'th'))

print custom_strftime('%B {TH}, %Y', time.localtime())
```

Answer (score 12):

```
"%s%s"%(day, 'trnshddt'[0xc0006c000000006c>>2*day&3::4])
```

But seriously, this is locale specific, so you should be doing it during internationalisation

Comment: the `0xc0006c000000006c>>2*day&3` part looks up 2 bits from a bit field for a corresponding day (hint: try `bin(0xc0006c000000006c)`, the last 2 bits are for day 0, days above 10 are all 0's). Then it takes that number 0-3 for the index of the first char, and skips 4 chars to get the 2nd char.

Comment: Any comments on where I can start learning about locale and internationalization?  My application does need to speak Spanish, so I'll probably need a more comprehensive solution like you say.

Comment: @Buttons840, Start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext, when you need to solve specific internationalisation problems, open more questions on SO

Comment: Sorry, on 2nd glance, "days above 10 are all 0's" should have been "days above 31 *would* all be 0's".

Comment: Gnibbler, how did you assemble this value ``0xc0006c000000006c``? I understand what it means, but how did you get all the bits in the right places?

Comment: @ThomasH, `hex(0b1100000000000000011011000000000000000000000000000000000001101100)`

Comment: @gnibbler That means, you've spelled that binary literal out by hand? Counting '1's and '0's?! How many typos did you make before you got it right ;-).

Comment: I downvoted this because I think handcrafted, unreadable binary maps are just a bad idea. I can't tell if it's correct (other than by writing a test that tests every value), it doesn't generalize and it's not that much more efficient. If performance matters that much, you shouldn't be doing it in Python. I'll upvote another response.

Comment: @Roy, did you miss the last sentence? All the hard coded answers here are "wrong". The correct place to do this stuff is in the i18n library

Comment: @gribbler: 1) How many people here took you seriously? 2) If I take your second sentence at face value, you could be implying that your code is acceptable if it was just in the right place. 3) Saying it belongs "during internationalization" is not necessarily correct -- you are making assumptions about the problem. Maybe the OP is writing an i18n library. Even if they're not, your response is not useful to solve their actual problem -- did you point them to a library? 4) Sarcasm doesn't fare well on StackOverflow.

Submit this to the Obfuscated Python contest instead.

Comment: Upvoted for hilarity.

Answer (score 3):

```
from time import strftime

print strftime('%A %B %dth')
```

### EDIT:

Correcting after having seen the answers of gurus:

```
from time import strftime

def special_strftime(dic = {'01':'st','21':'st','31':'st',
                            '02':'nd','22':'nd',
                            '03':'rd','23':'rd'}):
    x = strftime('%A %B %d')
    return x + dic.get(x[-2:],'th')


print special_strftime()
```

.

### EDIT 2

Also:

```
from time import strftime


def special_strftime(dic = {'1':'st','2':'nd','3':'rd'}):

    x = strftime('%A %B %d')
    return x + ('th' if x[-2:] in ('11','12','13')
                else dic.get(x[-1],'th')

print special_strftime()
```

.

### EDIT 3

Finally, it can be simplified:

```
from time import strftime

def special_strftime(dic = {'1':'st','2':'nd','3':'rd'}):

    x = strftime('%A %B %d')
    return x + ('th' if x[-2]=='1' else dic.get(x[-1],'th')

print special_strftime()
```

Comment: May 01th, May 02th, May 03th, hmm, I think you have a lisp.

Comment: @Thomas Wouters Worse than a lisp

Comment: @eyquem: After you edited, the answer does not need a down-vote, it was not a punishment, it was to indicate that the answer was wrong, now that it's not any more, no down-vote :)

Comment: +1 for leaving the lispy solution for prosperity :)

Comment: @Acom You mean 'posterity' , I think. On SO, we work for posterity, not prosperity !!

Comment: A typo, how embarrassing.. The only solution is to give you a large sum of money!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. The `time.strftime` function and the `datetime.datetime.strftime` method both (usually) use the platform C library's `strftime` function, and it (usually) does not offer that format. You would need to use a third-party library, like [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil).

Comment: Does `dateutil` allow you to format dates? I can't see anything mentioning it in the docs..