# How to get python date as below format?

Tags: python, date

Hi I need to get system date as below format in python

> **14th May 2021
>
> 31st December 2020
>
> 3rd April 2020**

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display the date, like "May 5th", using pythons strftime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891555/display-the-date-like-may-5th-using-pythons-strftime)

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strftime` function from the `datetime` module.

```
from datetime import date
mydate = date(2021, 5, 14) #14th May 2021
mydate.strftime('%d %b %Y')
```

However this doesn't get you the th suffix. For that you have to make a custom function.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt,date

def suffix(d):
    return 'th' if 11<=d<=13 else {1:'st',2:'nd',3:'rd'}.get(d%10, 'th')

def custom_strftime(format, t):
    return t.strftime(format).replace('{S}', str(t.day) + suffix(t.day))

print(custom_strftime('{S} %B %Y',  date(2021, 5, 14)))
```

Which will print

```
14th May 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `time` and format as below.

```
import time
day = time.strftime('%d')
day_endings = {
    1: 'st',
    2: 'nd',
    3: 'rd',
    21: 'st',
    22: 'nd',
    23: 'rd',
    31: 'st'
}
if day not in day_endings.keys():
    print(time.strftime('%dth %b %Y'))
else:
    print(print(time.strftime(f'%d{day_endings[day]} %b %Y'))
```

output

```
14th May, 2021
```

**Second test with ending in dict**

```
import time
day = 1

day_endings = {
    1: 'st',
    2: 'nd',
    3: 'rd',
    21: 'st',
    22: 'nd',
    23: 'rd',
    31: 'st'
}
if day not in day_endings.keys():
    print('wa')
    print(time.strftime('%dth %b %Y'))
else:
    print(time.strftime(f'1{day_endings[day]} %b %Y'))
```

1st May 2021

Comment: OP probably wants the suffixes ("th", "rd") as well.

Comment: Maybe yeah that could be true