# What are some ways to parse date/time from user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, user-input

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self, digits):   #digits='10/20/21'
        self.month = digits[:2]  #'10'
        self.day = digits[3:5]   #'20'
        self.year = digits[6:8]  #'21'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Dated this {self.day} day of {self.month}, 20{self.year}"

def checkday(date):        #add 'st', 'nd', 'rd', or 'th' to day
    if int(date.day) == 1 or int(date.day) == 21 or int(date.day) == 31:
        date.day += 'st'
    elif int(date.day) == 2 or int(date.day) == 22:
        date.day += 'nd'
    elif int(date.day) == 3 or int(date.day) == 23:
        date.day += 'rd'
    else:
        date.day += 'th'

def checkmonth(date):     #get name of month
    date.month = monthdic[date.month]

months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct','Nov', 'Dec']
monthdic = {str(i): month for i, month in zip(range(1,13), months)}

date = Date(input("Enter date (mm/dd/yy):\t"))
checkday(date)
checkmonth(date)

print(date)
```

a couple of errors that come down to one problem that i did not think of:

if it is january: `1/12/14` will not work because `self.month` is `1/12/14[:2]`.

```
Enter date (mm/dd/yy):  1/12/14
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "date.py", line 38, in <module>
    checkday(date)
  File "date.py", line 14, in checkday
    if int(date.day) == 1 or int(date.day) == 21 or int(date.day) == 31:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2/'
```

if i resort to `01/12/14`, this will also not work because `01` is `'01'` and `monthdic['01']` does not exist:

```
Enter date (mm/dd/yy):  01/12/14
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "date.py", line 39, in <module>
    checkmonth(date)
  File "date.py", line 28, in checkmonth
    date.month = monthdic[date.month]
KeyError: '01'
```

obviously

```
def __init__(self, digits):
    self.month = digits[:2]
    self.day = digits[3:5]
    self.year = digits[6:8]
```

is not the best approach, what are some good approaches (other than regex) ?

also one thing: would it be appropriate to call `checkdate()` and `checkmonth` inside `__init__`?

Comment: `self.month, self.day, self.year = map(int, digits.split("/"))`?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime()` is the canonical way to parse strings into dates. I'm not aware of any others.

Comment: @wjandrea no, that does not answer my question. also `if date.day.endswith('1'): date.day += 'st'` wouldn't work: `'12nd'` or `'13rd'`

Comment: @rain How doesn't it answer your question?

Comment: @rain Oops, I forgot about those. I deleted my comment.

Comment: @wjandrea i was looking for different approaches that i can have in the specific context

Comment: @wjandrea also what is up with the whitespace? every time i post on stackoverflow, there seem to be whitespace in the snippets that apparently make them not 'readable'. lol. vim has spaces to tabs enabled. not sure why the whitespace

Comment: There are also existing questions about getting ordinals, like [Display the date, like “May 5th”, using pythons strftime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5891555/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method to use would be the split method. You can split the text that is being entered with respect to `'/'`. So, something like `1/12/14` would become `[1, 12, 14]`. The rest is straightforward.

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self, digits):
        split = digits.split('/')
        self.month = split[0]
        self.day = split[1]
        self.year = split[2]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Dated this {self.day} day of {self.month}, {self.year}"
```

Answer (score 0):

as @MuhameedJaseem [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68010956/4518341): `split = digits.split('/')` and work with `split`. also improved the code as many suggested. code is now a tad bit more elegant.

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self, digits):
        self.month, self.day, self.year = digits.split('/')


    def __str__(self):
        return f"Dated this {self.day} day of {self.month}, {self.year}"



def checkday(date):

    if date.day[-1] == '1' and date.day[0] != '1':
        date.day += 'st'

    elif date.day[-1] == '2' and date.day[0] != '1':
        date.day += 'nd'

    elif date.day[-1] == '3' and date.day[0] != '1':
        date.day += 'rd'

    else:
        date.day += 'th'


def checkmonth(date):
    date.month = monthdic[date.month]


months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct','Nov', 'Dec']

monthdic = {str(i): month for i, month in zip(range(1,13), months)}



date = Date(input("Enter date (m/d/y):\t"))
checkday(date)
checkmonth(date)
```