# I am making a time display in python but it doesn't print what I want it to

Tags: python

My code is:

```
import time

local_time = time.localtime()
time_string_d = time.strftime("%d", local_time)
time_string_m = time.strftime("%m", local_time)
time_string_y = time.strftime("%Y", local_time)
time_string_hm = time.strftime("%H:%M", local_time)
day_st = ['1', '21', '31']
day_nd = ['2', '22', '32']
day_rd = ['3', '23']
day_th = ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', 
'19', '20', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30']

def month():
    if time_string_m == '1':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('January ', day())
    if time_string_m == '2':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('February ', day())
    if time_string_m == '3':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('March ', day())
    if time_string_m == '4':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('April ', day())
    if time_string_m == '5':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('May ', day())
    if time_string_m == '6':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('June ', day())
    if time_string_m == '7':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('July ', day())
    if time_string_m == '8':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('August ', day())
    if time_string_m == '9':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('September ', day())
    if time_string_m == '10':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('October ', day())
    if time_string_m == '11':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('November ', day())
    if time_string_m == '12':
        print('It is ' + time_string_hm)
        print('December ', day())
    else:
        print('There was an error in the month detecting system.')

def day():
    if time_string_d in day_st:
        print('st')
    if time_string_d in day_nd:
        print('nd')
    if time_string_d in day_rd:
        print('rd')
    if time_string_d in day_th:
        print('th')
    else:
        print('There was an error in the day detecting system.')
```

and I want it to print the following:

> It is (current time for example: 14:20)
> (current month for example: October, current day + /st/nd/rd/th for example 8th)

Like this:

```
It is 14:20
October 8th
```

Also if it fails then the following:

> There was an error in the month detecting system

or

> There was an error in the day detecting system.

What it actually prints out:

```
It is 14:20
There was an error in the day detecting system.
October  None
There was an error in the month detecting system.
```

Comment: Putting multiple `if` statements after each other does not do what you seem to think.

Comment: You already use `strftime`, so why not use it to build the entire string? `time.strftime("%B %#d");` → "October 8". (On non-Windows systems it's `time.strftime("%B %-d");`)

Comment: The only thing that needs special handling is "st, nd, rd, th", for that see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5891555/476. The rest can be done purely with the right `strftime` formatting string. Properly you'd use a localisation library like babel, which includes the "st, nd, rd, th" handling too…

Comment: I agree with the note left by deceze, that link's method should make things much easier to handle than chaining if-statements

Answer (score 1):

You should use single [if-elif-else](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) for example

```
x = 1
if x == 1:
    print(1)
elif x == 2:
    print(2)
else:
    print("else")
```

will print `1`, whilst

```
x = 1
if x == 1:
    print(1)
if x == 2:
    print(2)
else:
    print("else")
```

will print `1` then `else` because it has 2 if statements - if and if-else. You might use 0 or more `elif`s in single if statement, if you want to know more read linked docs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are chaining `if` statements instead of `elif`s, when your code is running, it checks each line, but the else statement runs in every case where:

```
if time_string_d in day_th:
```

is not true. As in, your function looks like this:

```
def day():

    if time_string_d in day_st:
        print('st')

    if time_string_d in day_nd:
        print('nd')

    if time_string_d in day_rd:
        print('rd')

    if time_string_d in day_th:
        print('th')
    else:
        print('There was an error in the day detecting system.')
```

and only this part matters for the else statement:

```
if time_string_d in day_th:
    print('th')
else:
    print('There was an error in the day detecting system.')
```