# Python equivalent of PHP's date()

Tags: php, python

For simple formats its easy to come up with equivalents

PHP:

```php
date("Y-m-d") === "2012-07-25";
```

Python:

```py
date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") == "2012-07-25"
```

But what is the Python equivalent of

```php
date("jS F Y") === "25th July 2012";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Date Ordinal Output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739241/python-date-ordinal-output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid I think you'll have to work the suffix out yourself:

```
>>> t = time.localtime()
>>> suffix = 'st' if t.tm_mday in [1,21,31] else 'nd' if t.tm_mday in [2, 22] else 'rd' if t.tm_mday in [3, 23] else 'th'
>>> time.strftime('%d%%s %B %Y', t) % suffix
'25th July 2012'
```

It's a bit English-centric for a programming language feature, so you can see why they didn't include it.

*Edited to add the "rd" suffix for 3rd and 23rd.

Comment: Yup, Guido van Rossum is dutch

Comment: @Patrick: this has nothing to do with Guido's nationality and everything to do with the C standard strftime routine. See http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

Comment: I knew different locales have different date formatting rules, I just thought there might be a Python package that implemented them. In particular it would be nice if there was a format specifier that would output "July 25th 2012" for en-US, "25th July 2012" for en-GB,  or "25 Juli 2012" for fr-FR. Guess I'll have to write it myself!

Comment: @Matt: My answer points you to such a package. Most date formatting does not absolutely need to include `th` and `nd`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But the date format my British clients require does. I don't think I'll get very far telling them that they can't have what they are paying for because it wouldn't work in Dutch :)

Comment: @Mat: Sorry, but again, this has nothing to do with Dutch. You can tell them about the Unicode standards though..

Comment: @Mat: Had to verify this; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English#Dates. UK dates can use either ordinal or cardinal numbers, with ordinals being slightly more formal.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library only supports the [standard C library strftime formatting codes](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), which are rather weak when it comes to localization. `%B` gives you the full month name in the locale your program is running under; if that's the English locale it'll give you 'April', but it could just as well give you 'Avril' if you are running on a french computer.

For web applications, you really want to use an external library like [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) to do that instead; Babel provides you with extra routines for formatting python `datetime` instances in different languages:

```
>>> from babel.dates import format_date
>>> format_date(d, format='long', locale='en')
u'April 1, 2007'
```

where `format='long'` is defined as a language-specific pattern.

Babel uses the [Unicode Locale Data markup language](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns) to define these patterns giving you access to large pre-defined locale libraries that define these patters for you. Note that the [grammatically correct way is to use cardinal, *not* ordinal numbers when formatting dates](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/writing-dates.aspx); British English allows for both ordinal and cardinal dates. As such the Unicode standard does not include ordinal post-fixes for dates.

Comment: I looked into Babel already and it looks great but I do need the ordinal suffixes.

Comment: Hrm, even though the LDML standard includes ordinals, it appears that Babel doesn't have an API to expose these (yet).

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%dth %B %Y")
```

For more details see
http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: This will print eg '1th July 2012' on the 1st of the month.

Comment: Good catch, didn't think of that one. Interesting observation by Martijn about ordinal/cardinal in spoken/written dates (in English)