# How to format date YYYY-mm-dd to day, month, day #

Tags: python, date

I'm trying to convert/format dates in Python..

Currently it outputs:

> 2014-01-08

I'd like the output to be:

> Monday, January 3rd

Having trouble understanding the documentation here, halp me format the date properly?

Comment: The standard library doesn't support ordinals (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.).

Comment: Please show the code that you're currently using and anything else you've tried.

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Date Ordinal Output?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/739241)

Answer (score 2):

You can't quite do this in one go. If you look at the docs for [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), there are format codes for the full weekday (`%A`) and month (`%B`), but there's nothing for the day of the month as an ordinal.

In general, whenever you want to do something `strftime` can't do, use as much of it as you can, and combine it with explicit code for the rest. Like this:

```
def ordinal(n):
    if 11 <= n <= 13:
        return '{}th'.format(n)
    if n%10 == 1:
        return '{}st'.format(n)
    elif n%10 == 2:
        return '{}nd'.format(n)
    elif n%10 == 3:
        return '{}rd'.format(n)
    else:
        return '{}th'.format(n)
```

Then, you can do this:

```
def my_format(dt):
    return '{} {}'.format(dt.strftime('%A, %B'), ordinal(dt.day))
```

I'm assuming that you're starting off with a `date` or `datetime` object. If not, you have to parse it first, of course. But that's easy:

```
datestring = '2014-01-08'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Maybe something like: `'{0:%A}, {0:%B} {1}'.format(dt, ordinal(dt.day))` and get rid of strftime call

Comment: @JonClements: That's shorter, but for a novice I'm not sure I want to explain that `str.format` calls `d.strftime` on `datetime` objects. The more explicit way gives you a much more obvious error if you accidentally call it on a string.

Comment: @JonClements: that can be shortened to `'{:%A, %B} {}'.format(dt, ordinal(dt.day))`; the full `strftime` format syntax can be used.

Comment: Is there a more obvious demonstration of this ability of `.format` besides a small example in [this section of the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)?  I had no idea `.format` could call `strftime` on a `datatime` object, and I'm not surprised because it seems that it is only mentioned as an aside, and not explicitly.

Comment: @SethMMorton: Yes. [`datetime.datetime.__format__`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__format__) is fully documented. If you already know that `format` and `str.format` call the `__format__` dunder-method hook, it's pretty easy to find out what the capabilities are for any builtin/stdlib classes, because they're all documented. If you didn't already know that (because, say, you didn't read the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) or the python-ideas discussion 7 years ago), it's a bit less discoverable.

Comment: @SethMMorton: In particular, [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#format) says "A call to `format(value, format_spec)` is translated to `type(value).__format__(format_spec)`, but [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) doesn't, and many people don't know to look at the builtin for more info on the method. (Also, if you're using Python 2.x, many of the docs improvements weren't back-ported.)

Comment: @abarnert Ah, and I am using python 2.x, so that's probably my issue. And I definitely was't programming 7 years ago so I didn't read those discussions :)  Thanks for the explanation and the links.