# What's the best way to convert a date in the form yyyy-mm-dd to a date using English month names?

Tags: python

What I mean is, let's say I have the date '2018-05-20'. I want it in the form of 'May 20th, 2018'. What is the best way to do this without brute-forcing (below, for example) so that you don't have to create a bunch of dictionary entries and then deal with mapping all the numbers for months and dates to their English representation?

```
monthDict = {}
monthDict['01'] = 'January'
monthDict['02'] = 'February'
monthDict['03'] = 'March'
monthDict['04'] = 'April'
monthDict['05'] = 'May'
monthDict['06'] = 'June'
monthDict['07'] = 'July'
monthDict['08'] = 'August'
monthDict['09'] = 'September'
monthDict['10'] = 'October'
monthDict['11'] = 'November'
monthDict['12'] = 'December'
```

Comment: You should look into [strftime() and strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: You can use [`calendar.month_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) instead of defining your own. It's an array indexed by integers, not a `dict` with keys that are strings, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse it in the existing format, and output the new.  There is an output `%B` that represents the full month.  Example:

```
import datetime
s = '2018-05-20'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')
print dt.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
```

Example:

```
$ python test.py 
May 20, 2018
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: np!  not sure why people are downvoting your question - it's basic but legit.  that sucks, sorry.

Comment: @FinnaBoi I thought it was meant to be `May 20th, 2018`?

Comment: There is no strftime option for the ordinal of the date (th/st/nd).  You'll have to write your own function for that, but you won't have to brute force it.  Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739241/date-ordinal-output

Comment: @keredson Appreciate the link. And yeah I'm just starting out with Python, so extra thanks to people who have your patience!