# Convert dates to letters with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am printing the current date using `print(now.strftime("%d-%B-%Y"))` which is working.

However, instead of it printing `21-November-2020`, I want it to print the suffix for each day so `21st-November-2020` instead. As well, it should do this for each day automatically (2nd, 5th, 30th...). Is this possible?

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Ordinal Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739241/date-ordinal-output)

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def suffix(d):
    return 'th' if 11<=d<=13 else {1:'st',2:'nd',3:'rd'}.get(d%10, 'th')

def custom_strftime(format, t):
    return t.strftime(format).replace('{S}', str(t.day) + suffix(t.day))

print(custom_strftime('{S}-%B-%Y', dt.now()))
```

Out:

```
23rd-September-2022
```

Based on the day, it will auto return the correct suffix, e.g., 1***st***, 3***rd***, 10***th***.